# Replace \\ with \ in FolderDialogBox.SelectedPath

Tags: c#

I am using folderdialogbox in one of my application. When a directory is selected and assigned to another string, I get a value like `C:\\test`

For some of the assignments, I would like the value of `c:\test`.

I researched on stackoverflow, but did not find any working answer. I tried all kind of replacement, but it does not work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

The Codes:

```
private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       folderBrowserDialog1.ShowNewFolderButton = false;

        if (folderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            string p = @folderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath; //=> Selected C:\ACTNT
            //removing @ in front of folderBrowserDialog1 does not change the situation
            strPathName.Text = p; // => display c:\ACNT
            con = "database = " + p; // => actual value "database = c:\\ACNT"
            UpdateTableName();
        }
    }
```

If I type manually in `strPathName` as `C:\ACNT` , the program runs fine.

Comment: Please post the code that you've used to solve the issue you face. From it, we can see the problem and help you.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting `C:\\test`?  I ask because the VS debugger displays \\ when the underlying string value is actually \.

Comment: I ran the code, removing `UpdateTableName();` since it's not relevant, adding `MessageBox.Show(con)` after `con = "database = " + p;` to see the concatenated result and the message box will show `database = c:\ACNT`. There's nothing wrong with the code.

Comment: dont forget to mark answer as accpeted if you got the info you want

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The other answers so far are talking about assigning string literals, but it sounds like you're *getting* this string via a GUI anyway, in which case that's irrelevant.

What *is* relevant is how you're determining that the string is actually `c:\\test`. I *strongly* suspect you're looking at it in the debugger - which automatically applies C# escaping when it displays the string.

If you just print it to the screen, or even example it character by character (e.g. call `ToCharArray()`) I think you'll find it only has a single backslash. Don't be fooled by the debugger.

Comment: I am not looking into the debugger. The value is added to another string. When this string is used by the system, it fails. The string is originally obtained through GUI (filebrowserdialog).

Comment: @NatwarLath: How are you viewing the string then? Perhaps something else is escaping it. Try printing out the length, or the characters one by one. FileBrowserDialog will *not* double the slashes like that.

Answer (score 0):

To specify \ in a C# string, escape it with another slash. eg string yourString = "C:\test";

If you specify "C:\test" what you're actually saying is "C:[tab character]est".

Answer (score 0):

Y donet you make use of @ example

```
string myvar = @"c:\myfile.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
string path = @"C:\\test";
path=path.Replace(@"\\", @"\");
```

Answer (score 0):

In front of the string value, try placing an `@`.
For example:

```
@"c:\test".
```

Answer (score 0):

Use either

```
string myvar = @"c:\myfile.txt";
```

or

```
string myvar = "c:\\myfile.txt";
```